# Is there any footage and/or photos of Germans surrendering towns and cities in the Western Front?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany

I heard that unlike the surrender ceremonies in the Eastern front, those on the western front were arranged to be solemn, festive and pompous, especially when the cities were conceded without fighting.

Thus I would be glad for pointing at any footage and/or photos showing German surrender ceremonies in 1944-1945 in the West.

Comment: Outside of the fighting in Germany itself (where surrender ceremonies could hardly be expected to have been festive), the Western Front was basically an intense, bitterly contested battle in a narrow area around Normandy, followed by an almost unopposed exploitation into open country. Except for fortified ports, there weren't many "surrender ceremonies" as such, just Allied patrols cautiously driving into some town, to be immediately mobbed by joyous crowds of civilians (sometimes amidst sniper fire, even.) More typical would be some kind of liberation ceremony held by the town authorities.

Answer (score 3):

German Surrender at Rheims. The below photograph comes up on many pages, etc when searching for information on the surrender at Reims

[image]

I also came across these videos. I cannot verify who posted the first one or where it originated from.

[German Bohemia Surrender](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&NR=1&v=3yQHtcVC5DQ)

[Germans Surrender at Reims (This one was sited as being posted by www.eto-history-group.fr/](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXWNm1EmasM)

Finally this [article](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2009/may/11/german-surrender-channel-islands-archive) may not be a picture or a video but it should be added. It is an article from the perspective of a British man(maybe a soldier) during the Channel Islands Surrender.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed it seems Youtube has many such videos. I especially interested not in signing ceremonies by in the footage of ceding the city control, the surrender of troops etc.

Comment: @Anixx It seems you would be very interested in some of those youtube videos. Enjoy